# I need a macro to separate a column of names into 4 different shifts

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, vba

Our system creates a report for accuracy. Our manager wants it separated by shifts. From those lists, it will go to a report 'by shift' along with the information on the row with each.

I need a macro which will separate the names by shift (I have a list for each shift), find the names on the master report from the Accuracy report and insert the relevant information into the the master report beside the correct name.
Is this doable?

```
**Selector**           **Pieces*   **Errors**   **Pieces%**
FIRST NAME LAST NAME   411         0            100
FIRST NAME LAST NAME   829         10           98.79
FIRST NAME LAST NAME   533         0            100
FIRST NAME LAST NAME   344         0            100
```

(this list includes about 100 names with the error status)

```
Grand Total            49918       100          99.8 name.
```

I am using Excel 2010.

Comment: Your question is nearly impossible to understand. It will be very difficult for anybody to help you unless you give a clearer explanation of what data you have and what results you want, complete with examples.

Comment: To answer the question you asked, Yes it's doable.   If you want specific help tho, you need to show your work and let us know where you are stuck. We can't create for you... We do and you will tell us why the creation can't work for you.

Comment: Where is the shift information?